# MinGW g++ creating undefined reference for std::basic_filebuf

Tags: c++, g++, linker-errors, mingw-w64, leveldb

i currently try to make JNI bindings for https://github.com/Mojang/leveldb-mcpe which can be found here https://github.com/GoMint/leveldbjni.

Compiling the project with the compile.sh in src/main/c/ hasn't been a problem under linux (ubuntu 18.04). The problem is that when i compile the same project with mingw64 in cygwin (g++) i get linker errors depending on which optimization level i choose.

The windows build script:

```
#!/bin/sh
CWD=$(pwd)

# First we start by this: you NEED cygwin with installed x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ for this to work
CXX="x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++"

# We compile with c++0x because leveldb uses it as preferred language level
CXX="$CXX -std=c++0x"

# Some shared library switches
CXX="$CXX -s -shared -fPIC"

# This build should use the libc memcmp instead of the builtin one
CXX="$CXX -fno-builtin-memcmp"

# Since we use a "emulated" windows build chain we need to define that we are windows blue (10)
CXX="$CXX -D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0603"

# Now some leveldb config (telling we are windows and we want the mcpe windows hacks)
CXX="$CXX -DMCPE_PLATFORM_WINDOWS_FAMILY -DOS_WIN -DCYGWIN -DWIN32 -DNDEBUG -DDLLX="

# Some general improvements
CXX="$CXX -O2"

# Includes
CXX="$CXX -I$JAVA_HOME/include/ -I$JAVA_HOME/include/win32/ -I$CWD/leveldb-mcpe/ -I$CWD/leveldb-mcpe/include/ -v"

# We need the zlib.h in a seperate folder (because mojang added it to the wrong folder zlib/zlib.h where the normal import is simply zlib.h)
mkdir -p "$CWD/include/zlib/"
cp /usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/zlib.h "$CWD/include/zlib/zlib.h"
CXX="$CXX -I$CWD/include/"

# Verify that the built cmd is correct
echo $CXX

# Build the windows version
$CXX leveldb-mcpe/db/builder.cc      leveldb-mcpe/db/c.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/db/db_impl.cc      leveldb-mcpe/db/db_iter.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/db/dbformat.cc     leveldb-mcpe/db/filename.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/db/log_reader.cc   leveldb-mcpe/db/log_writer.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/db/memtable.cc     leveldb-mcpe/db/repair.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/db/table_cache.cc  leveldb-mcpe/db/version_edit.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/db/version_set.cc  leveldb-mcpe/db/write_batch.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/db/snappy_compressor.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/db/zlib_compressor.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/db/zopfli_compressor.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/db/zstd_compressor.cc\
     \
     leveldb-mcpe/table/block.cc     leveldb-mcpe/table/block_builder.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/table/filter_block.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/table/iterator.cc  leveldb-mcpe/table/merger.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/table/table.cc     leveldb-mcpe/table/table_builder.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/table/two_level_iterator.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/table/format.cc\
     \
     leveldb-mcpe/util/arena.cc      leveldb-mcpe/util/bloom.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/util/cache.cc      leveldb-mcpe/util/coding.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/util/comparator.cc leveldb-mcpe/util/crc32c.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/util/env.cc        leveldb-mcpe/util/env_win.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/util/filter_policy.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/util/hash.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/util/histogram.cc  leveldb-mcpe/util/logging.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/util/win_logger.cc leveldb-mcpe/util/options.cc\
     leveldb-mcpe/util/status.cc\
     \
     leveldb-mcpe/port/port_win.cc leveldb-mcpe/port/port_posix_sse.cc\
     \
     io_gomint_leveldb_DB.cpp io_gomint_leveldb_Iterator.cpp io_gomint_leveldb_WriteBatch.cpp leveldbjni.cpp -o ../resources/leveldb-mcpe.dll -lz
```

Which compiles just fine but gives me this linker error:

```
/tmp/ccciWZjc.o:env_win.cc:(.text+0xe6f): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_close()«
/tmp/ccciWZjc.o:env_win.cc:(.text+0x1a18): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_close()«
/tmp/ccciWZjc.o:env_win.cc:(.text+0x1b7c): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_close()«
/tmp/ccciWZjc.o:env_win.cc:(.text+0x1da8): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_close()«
/tmp/ccciWZjc.o:env_win.cc:(.text+0x1f0c): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_close()«
/tmp/ccciWZjc.o:env_win.cc:(.text+0x2124): Warnung: weitere undefinierte Verweise auf »std::basic_filebuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_close()« folgen
```

When i remove the optimization level the linker produces this error:

```
/tmp/ccD8ugVG.o:env_win.cc:(.text+0xa2c): Warnung: undefinierter Verweis auf »std::basic_ofstream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_close()«
```

Comment: mingw **and** cygwin, are you sure? Normally those are alternatives

Comment: yes i only use the cygwin terminal and the mingw64 compiler chain to not use the cygwin ones to get rid of the cygwin runtime needed. i also compiled it with the cygwin compiler which also is fine

Comment: a little update, i also installed msys2 with the toolchain described here https://github.com/orlp/dev-on-windows/wiki/Installing-GCC--&-MSYS2 and zlib-devel installed and i'm getting the same result (without cygwin terminal, using the mingw64 one)

Comment: Are you running msys2.exe or mingw.exe? 
msys2.exe works with the cygwin compilers. If required mingw and libs for it, then use mingw.exe from msys folder.

Comment: I use mingw64.exe since I want a x64 build